# Woocommerce 3.7 Update: Filter not working any more - "If product is already in the cart" = Do nothing and show cart ($found_in_cart)

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I’ve added the following filter (see below) for the scenario that a customer adds another (individually sold, digital) product to the cart that is already in the cart.

It was a nice way to disable the kind of ugly “you cannot add another product” message in a case that happened and just show the cart (as a reminder that the product is already in the cart)

With the new 3.7 woocommerce update, the appearing circle on top of the ajax "buy button" is stuck in an endlessly spinning loop.

In the version before the circle started spinning, it stopped, the cart appeared to show the customer that the product is already in the cart.

Did woocommerce change the variables that are involved in the filter below or is there another easy fix that I'm not aware of?

```
// if product is already in cart, just go to cart and don’t show ugly “you cannot add another product” message
add_filter( ‘woocommerce_add_to_cart_sold_individually_found_in_cart’, ‘spark_redirect_to_cart’ );

function spark_redirect_to_cart( $found_in_cart ) {
if ( $found_in_cart ) {
wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_page_permalink( ‘cart’ ) );
exit;
}
return $found_in_cart;
}
```

Help is very much appreciated, thanks.
Or is this bug related to the flatsome theme I'm using.

Comment: Reports that directly to WooCommerce Github opening [an issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues) as nobody here handle software support.

Comment: yeah, sorry... reported it to github as you suggested... just wondering if anyone came across the same issue and found a solution for this scenario... at the end, I just want to get rid of the error/alert message if someone adds a digital product that is sold only individually a second time to the cart... would be great to add a filter that prevents the error message for this case and basically does nothing but maybe show the cart...